# How to enforce a partition filter in a view in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to expose a table as a view in order to redact PII and use authorised views to handle permissions however I can't figure out how to enforce the partition filter so that the user can enter it when querying the view.

I have tried to figure out using the new dynamic SQL but nothing I have works.

So for example in a normal query, it would be

```
WHERE DATE(source_timestamp) >= 'date here'
```

source_timestamp is the partition field, I want this when a user queries the view.

Any guidance you guys can give would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Yeah, sorry i have updated the question. I don't even know if its possible?

Comment: so you would like guidance on the particular query you would be using? have you checked this? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#scanning_a_range_of_tables_using_table_suffix

Comment: no thats not what i mean. When you query a partitioned table it will automatically fill out the date field the partition is against. However when you save that as a view, i want the users to be able to change that date field when they query the saved view

Comment: So you have partitioned tables by date, you create a view containing all of the tables and then you just use where clause to access a particular subset, does that fit your use case? is there something preventing you to do that?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of a partition table creation, there is an option called "Require partition filter" that you should enable. This forces the usage of a WHERE clause in your queries to prune the amount of partitions.

More information about this topic can be found in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#querying_partitioned_tables_2)

In your case, I'd say that you are missing that option in the tables that you are referencing in the view.

However, if you want to have parameters in your view, that is currently [not supported](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#api).

Comment: That requires it on the table yes but I want to create a view from that table and you have to put the partition filter in before you save the view. I want that to be a variable so that when a user queries the view they can enter the date they want